# Still having NSDateFormatter result issues even with NSTimezone properly set, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The result is still a day before, I'm just asking myself why, because the NSTimeZone is properly set and is the right one for my country (italy, rome)
here's my stub of code, any ideas?

```
    NSString *dateString = @"03/07/2008";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:[NSDateFormatter defaultFormatterBehavior]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [formatter release];
```

the result in dateFromString is this **2008-07-02 22:00:00 +0000**.

I've looked for other solutions but the common answer was to set the timezone correctly, in my case it is set properly but the problem still remains.

Comment: It's working just fine on my machine.  Have you tried it on the simulator and the phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct because by default the `NSDate` will return a UTC date in its description `+0000`. You are a couple of hours ahead of UTC so you get 22:00:00 for the day prior. I am -5 and my result UTC is **2008-07-03 04:00:00 +0000** (DST). The date is correct, it is just being displayed in UTC, if you are trying to display it correctly somewhere just use the date formatter to get a string again.

```
...
NSDate *dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"%@ : %@", dateFromString, stringFromDate);
```

**2008-07-03 04:00:00 +0000 : 03/07/2008**

Comment: +1 realizing that `-[NSDate description]` always prints the date in UTC is very important