# Wrong time with NSDate and NSTimezone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have two dates (written in two different NSString), for example

```
31/12/2011
```

and

```
31/03/2012
```

I have to check if today is in this range.

For read the date from the NSString, I'm doing this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:my_string];
NSLog(@"%@", mydate);
```

but, in this example, the log is this one

```
2011-12-30 23:00:00 +0000
2012-03-30 23:00:00 +0000
```

So it's one hour behind. 
I know that using

```
NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:my_date];
```

my string it will be ok, but I can't see if today is in the range using NSString (or not?)!

So I have to use NSDate, but how can I solve the "time zone" problem?

Also, I have this problem also using

```
[NSDate date];
```

It returns me one hour ago (and I don't want it, because if someone check at midnight, for the phone it will be the day before!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Still having NSDateFormatter result issues even with NSTimezone properly set, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957423/still-having-nsdateformatter-result-issues-even-with-nstimezone-properly-set-wh)

Answer (score 1):

The following should help:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
```

for more details, please check out [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c) ... It looks similar. The "EST" can be replaced with whichever time zone is required.

Comment: thanks, now it works... but not for `[NSDate date]` (which is the date right now): with this I have the time one hour ago (because I think it's not using the dateFormatter). How can I do it?

Comment: You will need dateFormatter to get it to the required timezone. Of course, you can use [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] and then calculate the offset by using "-(NSTimeInterval)secondsFromGMT"

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but it looks, like you don't need to take care about time zones in this case. If you have just dates in format dd/MM/yyyy, when you will parse it with NSDateFormatter, it will use current timezone by default. So, when you will be comparing with your today's date all 3 dates will be in the same timezone and date/time adjusting will not be performed.

Comment: If you do not set the timezone it will offset from GMT.  If you set it to 12am 1/1/2012 and do not specify a timezone, it will be 6pm 12/31/2011  in the EST timezone.

Comment: yep, i was not sure about this thing... however, the idea is to have the same timezone for all 3 NSDate values